# Laravel many to many relation with different key field

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, many-to-many

I have a problem with getting everything working... I have 3 tables: products, categories, category_product - working as many to many relation.

inside product I have:

```
id | product_id | lang | name
1 | 1 | pl | name1
2 | 1 | en | name2
3 | 2 | pl | name3
4 | 2 | en | name4
```

categories:

```
id | category_id | lang | name
1 | 1 | pl | name
2 | 1 | en | name
...
```

This is my relation in Product model:

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category', 'category_product', 'product_id', 'category_id');
}
```

I managed to make categories assignment to the product by:

```
$arr = [];
        foreach($request->categories as $cat){
            $arr[$cat] = array('product_id' => $product->product_id);
        }

        $product->categories()->sync($arr);
```

But now I have no idea how can I get categories in my product.
I try as

```
$product->categories
```

but it still doesn't know how to connect product_id from products table with product_id from category_product.

http://sklep.app/admin/products/2/edit - here I edit my product with "id" of 2 and when I assign categories, I assign them to product_id in order to have them assigned to all lang versions in the same way.

I would appreciate your help :)

Comment: If I understand your situation you have a many- to-many through a pivot table. That kind of relation is modelized by HasManyThrough http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#has-many-through. Have you tried this way?

Comment: But In this case I have to create model for my category_product table, am I right ? Is this the only solution here ? Because it looks like some kind of workaround

Comment: I think your problem is that your category_id is not unique though. Your relationship should be defined with the column `id` from the categories table OR change the table structure to: `category: category_id | name_pl | name_en ... `